# Item "Send to EventGhost" stuck in windows explorer context menu

Tags: windows-explorer, python, context-menu, plugins

I've tried the AutoRemote plugin for EventGhost 2 years ago however I still can not get rid of the "Send to EventGhost" button in the explorer context menu

[Context menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xrl4.png)

I've already searched trough the Registry menu with this guide: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/

And I've used ShellExView and ShellMenuView but I couldn't find anything there either.

All i could find remaining in my program files for EventGhost was this script (**init**.py):
https://paste.ofcode.org/XuBZhZQ2UGL9dHYbB7eVxz

I think they try to add the item to the context menu at line 139 but I'm not familiar with this code.

I hope somebody can help me.

==============

**Edit**
Fixed thanks to Keith Miller's answer:

I found the entry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\SendToEventGhost`

Comment: Your screenshot is so utterly lacking in context that it is useless. Is it a top-level context entry or under the **Send to >** submenu? For what object types does the option appear? Files? Folders?

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving enough context. It appears for all Files and not for folders and it's a top level context entry.

Comment: Then most likely found under: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found it under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\SendToEventGhost

Comment: Ahh!!! From your screenshot & descriptioni, I didn't realize it was an item in the SendTo submenu, I thought it was top-level. Regardless, glad you found the offending item.